# Dynamic position in a string

Tags: php

I'm thinking about how it is better to implement including of a string into another string on a few predefined positions.

For example, I want the tag `<i>some info</i>` to be inserted into the string:

`"This is an example %s of the position %s"`

In 2 different places: the 1st %s or the 2nd %s depending on some conditions, but not in both places.

I thought about using printf() with predefined position markers, like %1$s, %2$s. But I'm not sure how to elegantly implement it.

And also I thought about using an array dividing the string into pieces and then concatenate it, e.g.:

`$arr[0] = "This is an example";`

`$arr[2] = "of the position";`

And then pasting the string like this:

`$arr[1] = "<i>some info</i>";`

or

`$arr[3] = "<i>some info</i>";`

But it looks not very flexible.

Thanks.

Comment: [vsprintf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) allows you to make a call like `sprintf()`, but with an array of values.... use your condition logic to order an array containing your `some info` text, and empty entries for the positions you don't want to filll based on the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `vsprintf()`, like this:

```
// Do the magic of determining positions and create an array
$replaceArray = array('','<i>some info</i>','');

$Placeholder = "This is an example %s of the position %s";    
$Result = vsprintf($Placeholder, $replaceArray);    
echo $Result;
```

You can generate the replaceArray dynamically, and could work with variables to determine the 'some info' value, and the 'empty' value for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sprintf()`, as described in the comment, like this:

```
$StringToInsert = "<i>some info</i>";
$StringToIgnore = NULL;
$Placeholder = "This is an example %s of the position %s";    
$Result = sprintf($Placeholder, $StringToInsert, $StringToIgnore);    
echo $Result;
```

Where you can use your logic to order the `$StringToInsert / $StringToIgnore` to place the strings within the placeholder.

> This is an example *some info* of the position

Comment: Like stated in the comment you're referring to, it's probably easier to use vsprintf, taking an array as second argument.